# Want to retreive data in required format from SQL SERVER table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a view as follows:

```
id paperid papercode papername marks1 marks2 total
1  1       001       paper-1   10     35     45
2  2       001       paper-2   12     40     52
3  3       002       paper-3   9      30     39
```

Now, I want data as below:

```
id paperid papercode papername marks1 marks2 total
1  1       001       001       22     75     97
3  3       002       paper-3   9      30     39
```

Comment: Add a few more rows with sample table data, having different paperid's etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

```
select min(id),min(paperid),papercode,min(papername),sum(marks1),sum(marks2),sum(marks3)
from tablename
group by papercode
```